# Overlapping check between two polygon

Tags: java, geometry

I have a two polygon shape draw using HTML5 canvas(GWT). I have all the points for two polygon shape. Means I have the list of points for draw this type of polygon.

Below image showing two polygon intersect or overlapping each other. Now I am searching for a solution how to find two polygon "intersect or not" using java? I am using pure java programming without using any third library.

[image]

I have another issue. For explaining this issue I am attaching another image below.

[image]

This is the another case when one Polygon inside of another Polygon. In this scenario how to calculate minimum distance between two polygon in negative?

Answer (score 2):

Using Postgis Api Using You get Information That Two Polygon intersect or not . Find Following Link As Reference 
http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sweepline paradigm.

Consider the horizontal lines passing through the vertexes of either polygons. Two consecutive lines cut out slabs (trapezoids).

[image]

As the slabs are simple, convex polygons, checking them for intersection is straightforward: it suffices to detect overlap of the bases (mind the case where they form an X cross).

Now the whole process can be decomposed as

- sorting the vertices of both polygons by increasing ordinates; for every vertex, remember to what polygon it belongs and what are its neighbors with a higher ordinate (none, one or two);
- scanning the vertices by increasing ordinate, while maintaining a list of the edges that are intersected (it is called the active list). Every time you move to another vertex, update the active list;
- testing the slabs for intersection.